# Vue.js - How to increment the index by value 2 in vue v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The example code is below:
In this code, `<ul>` executes the loop 7 times, But I need it to print arr[0], arr[1] in the `<li>` tag respectively. But, in the next time, I want the index value increment by 2, so that it prints arr[2], arr[3] and again increment the index value by 2, index becomes 4 and it prints arr[4] and arr[5] and so on. Thank you in advance for the solution.

```
<ul class="columns" v-for="index in 7" :key="index">
    <li>
        arr[index]
    </li>
    <li>
        arr[index+1]
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no step definition in `v-for` loop, but you could do the following logic to to achieve what you want :

```
 <ul class="columns" v-for="index in [...Array(7)].map((_,i)=>i).filter(i=>i%2===0)" :key="index">
        <li>
            {{index}}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{index+1}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

but it's very recommended to define a computed property that returns `[...Array(7)].map((_,i)=>i).filter(i=>i%2===0)` like  :

```
computed:{
  evenNumbers(){
    return [...Array(7)].map((_,i)=>i).filter(i=>i%2===0)
  }

}
```

```
<ul class="columns" v-for="index in evenNumbers" :key="index">
        <li>
            {{index}}
        </li>
        <li>
            {{index+1}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

`[...Array(7)]` will give an array of undefined items  :

```
 [undefined,undefined,....]
```

we use map method which as first parameter the current value which is in this case an `undefined` value represented by `_` (just choosing a short name) and the second parameter which is the current index which we want to return it instead of `_` then filter the returned indexes which are multiple of 2 `i%2===0`

Comment: return [...Array(7)].map((_,i)=>i).filter(i=>i%2===0) , Here ....Array(7) is an array variable and map((_,i) here _ represents what ?

Comment: please check my edited answer, i added some explanation

Comment: I worked with your suggestions. It displayed correctly. But, additionally, It prints the 8th index (which is empty) also. since, the total count is 7 only. when it gets into the loop it prints 7th index and index+1 i.e., 8th element also. How to solve it ?

Comment: the second `li` should be `<li v-if="index+1<=7">{{index+1}}</li>`

Answer (score 3):

What do you think about this solution (maybe not so elegant, but it will give what you expect to get, I hope):

```
<template v-for="index in arr" :key="index">
    <ul v-if="index % 2 === 0" class="columns">
        <li>
            {{ arr[index] }}
        </li>
        <li v-if="!!arr[index+1]">
            {{ arr[index+1] }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
<li>
        arr[index==0?index:(index+index)]
    </li>
    <li>
        arr[index==0?index+1:(index+index+1)]
</li>
```

Comment: But, it doesnot print the 1st 2 array values

Comment: @SUSINDHAR In your question, the index is starting from one instead of zero it seems